# Ionic 2/Firebase - Reorder items from Firebase

Tags: firebase, ionic2, angularfire2

I am currently making an Ionic 2 application. I would like the user to be able to reorder a list of items that is displayed from the database. However, I keep getting this error:

> TypeError: array.splice is not a function at reorderArray

There seem to be a problem with my FirebaseListObservable but I do not know what it is. Any help is much appreciated!

Below is my code for the following:

```
export class ManageFavouritesPage {

      fireAuth: any;
      items: FirebaseListObservable<any[]>;

      constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public af: AngularFire, private toastCtrl: ToastController, public authData: AuthData) {

        let userid = this.authData.getID();
        this.items = af.database.list(`/users/${userid}/favourites`)

        console.log(this.items);
      }


      reorderItems(indexes) {
        this.items = reorderArray(this.items, indexes)
      }
```

Comment: `list` returns an observable; it does not return an array: https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/3-retrieving-data-as-lists.md

Comment: Is there any way where i can return an array? I'm relatively new to code development and thus i might have missed out on some of the basics.

Comment: No, you have to [subscribe to the observable](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/manual/overview.html) to get it.

Comment: So i tried subscribing to the observable. However i get the following error: Type 'Subscription' is not assignable to type 'FirebaseListObservable<any[]>. Property '$ref' is missing in type 'Subscription'

Comment: lEh its okay I finally did it. Thanks alot for the help! Much appreciated!